# Comparing current and previous values of a looped variable

Tags: batch-file

In a DOS batch file, I iterate through folders and sub-folders to find *.txt files.

```
 FOR /R %ROOT_IN% %%F in (*.txt) do (echo Found : %%F)
```

The text files are all versioned and called like this : 
MytextA_v01, MytextA_v02, MytextA_v03 etc...
MytextB_v05, MytextB_v05, MytextB_v07 etc...

I want to find out what is the latest version of MytextA and MyTextB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "root_in=%cd%"

    for %%a in (A B) do (
        set "found="
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%c in (
            'cmd /q /e:on /c "for /r "%root_in%" %%b in (mytext%%a_v*) do echo %%~nb;%%~fb"^|sort /r'
        ) do if not defined found set "found=%%d"
        echo !found!
    )
```

This will simply, for each of the two sets of files, generate a list, reverse ordered on the name of the file, so the first element in the list is the last file of the set.

**EDITED** - As the naming indicated in the original question does not reflect the real naming of the files, the filtering logic of the previous code is not adecuated to this problem. But the search part is (as long as the numbering in files is coherent, as it "seems" from the original question). So, this is a hybrid batch/javascript file (save as batch file)

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root_in=%cd%"

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (
        'cmd /q /e:on /c "for /r "%root_in%" %%z in (*_v??????????.??????????) do echo %%~nz:%%~fz"^|findstr /i /r /c:"_v[0-9][0-9]*:" ^|sort /r^|cscript //nologo //e:JScript "%~f0"'
    ) do echo %%b

    endlocal
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************
    var stdin=WScript.StdIn, stdout=WScript.StdOut, r=/^(.*)_[vV][0-9]+:/, previous=null, current;
    while (!stdin.AtEndOfStream){
        if (previous !== (current=(line=stdin.ReadLine()).match(r)[1])) { 
            stdout.WriteLine(line); previous = current 
        };
    };
```

It does the same work searching for "versioned" files, and getting the filename part and the full path to the file. This list is filtered to only process records that match the "versioning", sorted in reverse order (so the last version is the first record in set) and the list is filtered in the javascript part of the script, returning only the first record in each set of files. This list is then processed in the `for %%a` batch part, echoing to console the full path to the last version of each "versioned" file.

Comment: This relies too much on the fact that files are either A or B. Sorry to have been misleading earlier, but files can be called like "anything_v12.txt". This why I started iterating through *.txt initially. Update much appreciated.

Comment: @user3464224, Are you at least trying to retrieve the last file in the list from a know set of lists or does it need to adapt automatically to the existing set of files in disk?

Comment: It does need to adapt automatically to each set to find the last version number. The base name of the set can be "anything".

Comment: @user3464224, updated code in answer. See the "edited" part. Adapt as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "root_in=u:\sourcedir"
SET "target1=mytexta_v"
SET "target2=mytextb_v"
SET "nlatest1="
SET "nlatest2="
SET "flatest1="
SET "flatest2="
FOR /R %ROOT_IN% %%F in (*.txt) do (
 SET "test=%%~nF"
 SET "test=!test:%target1%=!"
 IF /i "%target1%!test!"=="%%~nF" IF /i "%%~nF" gtr "!nlatest1!" (
  SET "nlatest1=%%~nF"&SET "flatest1=%%F"
 )
 SET "test=%%~nF"
 SET "test=!test:%target2%=!"
 IF /i "%target2%!test!"=="%%~nF" IF /i "%%~nF" gtr "!nlatest2!" (
  SET "nlatest2=%%~nF"&SET "flatest2=%%F"
 )
)
ECHO latest texts are %flatest1% and %flatest2%

GOTO :EOF
```

(I used my `U:` drive for testing)

Comment: This relies too much on the fact that files are either A or B. Sorry to have been misleading earlier, but files can be called like "anything_v12.txt". This why I started iterating through *.txt initially. Update much appreciated.